# Navigate to cell in a notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells

Assume the following notebook of Rubi rules

```
nb = Import["https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/Rubi/raw/master/IntegrationRuleNotebooks/1%20Algebraic%20functions/1.1%20Binomial%20products/1.1.1%20Linear/1.1.1.1%20(a%2Bb%20x)%5Em.nb", "NotebookObject"];
```

If you open all cell-groups, you find that at the deepest level, there are `"Code"` cells. What is a pragmatic way to open this notebook in read-only mode and navigate to the n-th (say 18th) code cell automatically, so that the user directly sees the `Int` definition?

Functions that are helpful are `NotebookFind`, `SelectionMove`, `Cells`, and friends, but I feel my hacks are not entirely beautiful and this may be a question of general interest. So I would be delighted if you give me your best shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it fit your needs:

```
target = Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Code"][[5]](*5th cell*)
SelectionMove[target, All, CellGroup]
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "SelectionOpenAllGroups"]]
SelectionMove[target, All, CellContents]
```

?

[image]